# Qt: what class should I use for matrices instead of QMatrix?

Tags: qt, matrix

The documentation for QMatrix says it's obsolete and is strongly unadvised to use. Ok, but what should I use instead to store a matrix?
I have even posted a bug report on the [Qt Documentation Bug tracker](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-25430) but they didn't respond.

Comment: They say to use QTransform in the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmatrix.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QMatrix was specifically for 2D transformations and QTransform replaces it for that purpose. If you're looking for regular matrix classes for 3D work or linear algebra, then Qt has QMatrix4x4 and QGenericMatrix.

Comment: QGenericMatrix is the closest to what I needed but still I ended up writing it another way because QGenericMatrix is a template and therefore needs to know the matrix size at compile time.

Comment: Good that you got it working despite those problems. You'll get more useful answers if you take a step back and aim your question at the problem you're trying to solve, rather than asking about details of a potential solution. Just something to keep in mind for next time.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to do. The replacement for QMatrix is [QTransform](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtransform.html), so you should use that if it will accomplish what you want. It's worth noting that neither QMatrix nor QTransform are really matrices in the mathematical sense.

If you're talking about ordinary mathematical matrices, you should look to any of the existing C++ matrix libraries (a quick Google search turns up a number of results), or write your own matrix class. I was recently working on a project where I needed to do multiplication of small (2x2) matrices, so I just designed the class myself. It was quite easy.

EDIT: By the way, that's not a bug, so you should try to remove the report, if it's possible.

Comment: Actually, as far as I can see, QTransform and, surprisingly, QMatrix are both 3x3 only, so they can't be used for general matrix tasks. So I have to write a matrix class myself... Ok, I know that's easy but isn't it strange for Qt not to have such a basic class? What for the bug - ok, in this case it's not a bug, I've closed the report.

Comment: @Psycho IMO QTransform and QMatrix aren't actually matrices. They just hold values that Qt has arranged to look like a matrix in the documentation. You can't do any type of matrix math on them. I think that that is probably part of why they switched from QMatrix to QTransform... because it isn't really a matrix. Anyways, the bright side is that matrix math really isn't complicated to code. You just have to overload the relevant operators. I think it would have been nice for them to include this in Qt, but I can see why they didn't.

Comment: @Psycho If you're looking for regular matrix classes for 3D work or linear algebra, then Qt has QMatrix4x4 and QGenericMatrix. QMatrix was specifically for 2D stuff and QTransform replaces it for that purpose.

Comment: Btw, it would be a legitimate documentation bug had the alternative gone unmentioned, but it does state in QMatrix's documentation: "QTransform is the recommended transformation class in Qt."

Comment: @Slavik QGenericMatrix seems to be the answer! If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Psycho Actually, the correct answer to your question is QTransform.

Comment: @Anthony I think it would be the answer if I asked just about a replacement for QMatrix, but I actually asked about a class to store matrices (i.e., generic matrices) with an assumption that QMatrix was an obsolete class for that purpose. Don't you agree? Maybe I should edit the question to clarify it?

Comment: @Psycho You asked about a replacement for QMatrix, so we assumed you knew what it was, and that it's not a generic matrix for matrix math. So yes, I think QTransform is the correct answer. The answer you were looking for is the answer to a different question. Further, I think it's rude to offer acceptance to someone in the comments of someone else's answer. However, points don't matter to me (other than being fun), so no hard feelings either way.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to be rude. Thanks for your time anyway.